# Instagram API OAuthPermissionsException

Tags: php, instagram-api

I'm trying to implement images by tags on my site.

I'm using curl to get my API request.

Here is the URL that I'm using in curl

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/football/media/recent?access_token=3949591453.1677ed0.3d18a0cdb1664ca58704809bde72acf6
```

But every time I get the following response

{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}

Please help me with this and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For `tags` API, you need `public_content` scope during authentication, if not you will get error.